# Eliminate javascript from HTML with XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to transform an HTML report into XML, but some javascript in the file is throwing errors, due to statements with a less-than character (e.g., `for(var i=0; i<els.length;i++)` ). I thought I could eliminate the javascript with the following template, which should remove entire script nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="script"/>
```

I assumed the XSLT processor would simply skip over the entire script nodes, but it's still throwing the same errors. I also tried adding this one:

```
<xsl:template match="script/text()"/>
```

No luck. If I manually remove all the javascript from the file, my transform works, but that's not practical as I need to create and run a daily automated process on these HTML files to extract some data in the HTML tables.

Comment: So which XSLT processor do you use, which XML parser? On some platforms/with some processors it is easy to switch to an HTML parser instead of an XML parser if you want to feed HTML to XSLT, e.g. for Java you can use TagSoup, on .NET SgmlReader. But the usual use of XSLT is to process well-formed XML with an underlying XML parser that is supposed to object to any XML syntax errors and an unescaped less than sign is a syntax error in XML.

Comment: I am using Oxygen to run the transform. It offers several options and I had chosen Saxon-EE 9.6.0.7. Tried several others after reading your post, but no luck. I don't see any option to specify HTML as input.

Comment: Ask the oXygen support on how to set up an HTML parser like TagSoup to be used for parsing the input. Or at least tell us exactly which version of oXygen that is.

Comment: I have oXygen Developer 18.1 installed. This approach my not be the best since the HTML is not necessarily even well-formed when I receive it. I'm realizing that the XSLT processor must build a DOM tree before processing, so anything that is not well-formed will be a problem.

Comment: https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18.1/ug-editor/tasks/import-html.html suggests there is an HTML import feature so try whether that helps. Of course there are standalone applications like HTML Tidy I think you can use outside of the XSLT processsing to first convert your HTML to XHTML.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I had been wondering if there was a way to run Tidy from oXygen. Really should have researched that before coming here, but my post could end up helping someone else, so it's not a waste.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, XSLT will only process well-formed XML input: it's not designed to process other formats like HTML.

However, XSLT will generally accept input from a parser that delivers a stream of events that looks sufficiently like an XML stream. This allows parsers like TagSoup and validator.nu to be used as a front-end to your XSLT processor.

Saxon packages this up with a parse-html() function that invokes TagSoup to parse HTML input and turn it into a DOM-like tree (actually an XDM tree) that it can process as if it came from XML.

validator.nu is a more up-to-date HTML parser than TagSoup, but you would have to do a little more work to integrate that.

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered by Martin Honnen in the comments:

oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18.1/ug-editor/tasks/… suggests there is an HTML import feature so try whether that helps. Of course there are standalone applications like HTML Tidy I think you can use outside of the XSLT processsing to first convert your HTML to XHTML.